# balls moving away from cursor project in processing

Tags: processing

I am trying to make a program that uses an array to display 100 balls and vectors to make these balls move away from the cursor. I commented out of the vectors due to my lack of knowledge, but still all 100 balls are stuck in the top left corner when I use the processing ide. This same code (without vectors) works on repl.it using processing.

````
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float r1;
  float b1;
  float g1;
  float d;
  float xSpeed;
  float ySpeed;
  /*PVector mouseLocation;
  PVector ballLocation;
  PVector ballVelocity;
  PVector repulsionForce;
  float distanceFromMouse = repulsionForce.mag();*/
  
  ball(float x,float y)
  {
   
    d = random(10,30);
    r1= random(0,255);
    b1= random(0,255);
    g1= random(0,255);
    xSpeed = random(-4,4);
    ySpeed = random(-4,4);
   /* PVector mouseLocation = new PVector(mouseX,mouseY);
    PVector ballLocation = new PVector(x,y);
    PVector ballVelocity = new PVector(xSpeed,ySpeed);
     PVector repulsionForce = PVector.sub(ballLocation,mouseLocation); */
   
  
  }
  void render()
  {
    fill(r1,g1,b1);
    ellipse(x,y,d,d);
  }
  void move()
  {
    //ballLocation.add(ballVelocity);
    x = x + xSpeed;
    y = y + ySpeed;
  }
  void bounce()
  {
    if(x > width - d/2)
    {
      xSpeed = -xSpeed;
    }

    if(x < 0 + d/2)
    {
      xSpeed = -xSpeed;
    }

    if(y > height - d/2)
    {
      ySpeed = -ySpeed;
    }

    if(y < 0 + d/2)
    {
      ySpeed = -ySpeed;
    }
  }
  void curs()
  {
    
    /* if (distanceFromMouse < 100) {
     repulsionForce.normalize();
     repulsionForce.mult(map(distanceFromMouse, 0, 100, 2, 0));
     ballVelocity.add(repulsionForce);
    }
    ballLocation.add(repulsionForce); */
  }
}

ball[] balls = new ball[100];
float x;
float y;
void setup()
{
  size(600, 400);
  x = random(0,width);
  y = random(0,height);
  for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    balls[i] = new ball(x,y);
  }
}

void draw()
{
  background(50);
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    balls[i].render();
    balls[i].move();
    balls[i].bounce();
    balls[i].curs();
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I fixed your code. Here's the result:

[image: BOUNCE!]

Your principal problem is a matter of [scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/). When you have several variables going by the same name, the scope will decide which one shadows which one, and there was a lot of confusion going on in there. Also, you don't seem to understand exactly what is going on with all those coordinates. You don't need a `x` `y` floats to track the ball's location of you already have a `PVector ballLocation` which does it for you.

So here's what I did: once I realized what was going on, I...

1. Eliminated every unneeded xy variables and replaced them by the PVectors which were designed to do the same job.
2. Reorganized the ball class's update order. Instead of `render -> move -> bounce -> curs` I set it as `move -> render` while making sure that `move` contains calls to `bounce` and `curs` in this order: `bounce -> curs -> move`. The idea is that it will be easier to track edge cases like the balls going off screen if you do it in this order: calculate if they need to change direction, calculate changes in velocity, apply changes to the position then draw it on screen.
3. Modified `curs` so it changes the velocity of the ball, not it's position. I centralized the position's modification so everything will affect the velocity instead, so you have to check for edge cases in only one place. If there were 2 mouse cursors on screen somehow, both would affect the ball's position by applying pressure on it, not by moving it around.
4. The `repulsionForce` must be recalculated for every ball at every frame, or else they will never take into account the current location of the mouse. Fixed that.
5. When a ball tries to exit the screen, an adverse move was added so they don't disappear offscreen. This is not a current problem but it was going to be one at some point, so I fixed it before you have to deal with it.

Here's the code:

```
Ball[] balls = new Ball[100];

void setup()
{
  size(600, 400);
  for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    balls[i] = new Ball(random(width), random(height));
  }
}

void draw()
{
  background(50);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    balls[i].move();
    balls[i].render();
  }
}

class Ball
{
  float r1;
  float b1;
  float g1;
  float d;
  PVector ballLocation;
  PVector ballVelocity;
  PVector repulsionForce;
  float distanceFromMouse;

  Ball(float x, float y)
  {
    d = random(10, 30);
    r1= random(0, 255);
    b1= random(0, 255);
    g1= random(0, 255);
    ballVelocity = new PVector(random(-4, 4), random(-4, 4));
    ballLocation = new PVector(x, y);
    repulsionForce = PVector.sub(ballLocation, new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
  }

  void render()
  {
    fill(r1, g1, b1);
    ellipse(ballLocation.x, ballLocation.y, d, d);
  }

  void move()
  {
    bounce();
    curs();
    ballLocation.add(ballVelocity);
  }

  void bounce()
  {
    if (ballLocation.x > width - d/2 || ballLocation.x < 0 + d/2)
    {
      ballVelocity.x = -ballVelocity.x;
      ballLocation.add(ballVelocity);
    }

    if (ballLocation.y > height - d/2 || ballLocation.y < 0 + d/2)
    {
      ballVelocity.y = -ballVelocity.y;
      ballLocation.add(ballVelocity);
    }
  }

  void curs()
  {
    repulsionForce = PVector.sub(ballLocation, new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
    if (repulsionForce.mag() < 100) {
      repulsionForce.normalize();
      repulsionForce.mult(map(distanceFromMouse, 0, 100, 2, 0));
      ballVelocity.add(repulsionForce);
    }
  }
}
```

Take some time to take it in and let me know if there's any explanations you need about it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. I had fixed it over the past day, but your improvements helped a lot as I did run into them being able to go off-screen and this way of tracking the mouse and its effect is a lot better. I have one question though: Where/how could I limit the ball velocity, would something like `ballVelocity.limit(6);` in the main Ball method work?

Comment: I would place such mechanism in the `move()` method, right before the `ballLocation.add(ballVelocity);` line. You could create a method to do this but as this project won't become a huge code base you can code it right there instead, it won't affect readibility.

Comment: You can implement it by checking if each velocity is higher than the decided ceiling and attribute the ceiling value to the velocity if it's too high. Like this: `if (ballVelocity.x > 6) {ballVelocity.x = 6;}`, but instead of the number "6" you should use a modal variable (which is owned by the class) so some balls can be slightly faster or slower... if you like the idea.

Comment: Don't forget that velocity can also be a negative number, you'll have to check both for positive "too high" values and negative "too low" values, both for x and y velocities.